# Dynamic relative layout in android

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, android-relativelayout

I am trying to have two images on tp of each other. I can have it work fine with an xml file but I would like to do this dynamically. ctdeasyone is a transparent image.

So this works fine..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/bck1" 
        android:src="@drawable/fish2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/bck2" 
        android:src="@drawable/ctdeasyone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I do this. only the second image shows up (it is the transparent one.)  Can any of the experts advice on this? Newbbie here... This is my first question. TIA.

```
public class TwoPicksOnEachOther extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Grabbing the Application context         
        final Context context = getApplication();                   

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);                   

        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);         
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish2);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.addView(iv,lp);        

        // Creating transparent image
        final ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ctdeasytwo);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.addView(iv2,lp2);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);

    }        

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to put it in the emulator and play with it for a while until I saw it:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish2);
(...)
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ctdeasytwo);
```

You're never setting the image resource for iv2!

I changed that and now I see two images as expected.

Comment: Aleadam, I am trying to vote your answer up but it says I need 15 reputations. What a bug! I am setting iv.setImageResource twice. Never noticed. Works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @George yes, you new users can accept answers but not upvote. It took me a while to figure that bug out also!

Comment: maybe there is someting I don't get. I was suposed to get 5 reputations for voting up, but I can't vote up becasue I need 15 reputations. So how do you get these reputations??? When I figure it out, I will come back to vote you so you can get your 10.

Comment: You get +5 **for upvotes from others** on your won questions, or +10 for upvotes on your own answers. I upvoted now your question because it's well-written, with a clear problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) .  Since you want the images right on top of each other.

Comment: Even though the xml works perfect with relative layout you are suggesting to do this with FrameLoyout? I will try this if no else can help with the code above. I mean, it works with xml why not dynamically?

Comment: Just reiewed the FrameLyout you suggested. Very intersting as you suggested. I will try as sson as kids go to bed.