# How to set parameter for the dynamically created button?

Tags: android, button

I have created button dynamically now i want to set parameter such as (layout_marginTop or layout_marginRight) to the dynamically created button how can i do this i am using RelativeLayout  layout.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797076/dynamic-relative-layout-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change button's `LayoutParams`:

```
View button = /* ... */;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(button.getLayoutParams());
p.topMargin = /* ... */;
p.rightMargin = /* ... */;
// or use p.setMargins() method.
button.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the Following code fro this..

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            lp.setMargins(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);

button.setLayoutParams(lp);
```